# VBA - Converting a mixed row ( Data Type wise) to Date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have an excel sheet, one of the columns is mixed with Dates and Dates that has been copied to it as text ( see below ).

I dont manage to convert the text type to Date type, i need to do it though VBA to add it to some automation im working on. is there a way to do this at all ?

I noticed excel is looking for format like this 03/09/2016  23:39:57  and it doesn't like 3/21/16 11:07:22 PM, apparently  this is my case :) every look i run i get ( obviously data mismatch ), in the image bellow the spoken column is "C"

thx :)

[ExcelSheet bad Date  format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdFOP.jpg)

Comment: Check out the function datevalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming wvery bad dates are MM/DD/YYYY, then you could use the following code that I wrote for you:

```
   Sub main()

    Dim celda As Range
    Dim s_date As String
    Dim s_time As String
    Dim validate_date As String
    Dim valid_date As String
    Dim date_arr() As String
    Dim rango As Range
    Dim limit As Long

    limit = Columns("B").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "B")).Row - 1
    Set rango = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & limit)


    ' works only for date values, another value would return non expected values
    For Each celda In rango
        validate_date = Left(celda.Value, 1)
        If validate_date <> "" Then
            If Not celda.Rows.Hidden Then
                If validate_date <> "0" Then
                    s_date = Trim(Mid(celda.Value, 1, InStr(1, celda.Value, " ") - 1))
                    s_time = Trim(Mid(celda.Value, InStr(1, celda.Value, " "), Len(celda.Value) - InStr(1, celda.Value, " ")))

                    date_arr = Split(s_date, "/")

                    valid_date = date_arr(1)
                    valid_date = valid_date & "/0" & date_arr(0)
                    valid_date = valid_date & "/" & date_arr(2)
                    valid_date = valid_date & " " & s_time

                    celda.Offset(0, 1).Value = CDate(valid_date)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next celda

End Sub
```

In order to use this code you should insert one empty column to the right from target. Second, you should to select entire C column and run the macro.

**Edit 1.** Ok, this macro autoselect column B. Select column dates is not necessary now.

Comment: im writing it again  :   Hi Dani, thx for the efforts I appreciate it, it works nice nice :) this code suppose to go between other Code I already wrote in order to complete the automation im working on, i have a question: how can i change the function to aim to column B from the  2nd ( B2)  to the end of columns, and copy the modified cell to the parallel cell on column C ? is it possible if the cell is already a date format simply copy the cell as is to  columns C ? last question - is it possible to make the selection automatically without a user interfering ? so far the code is so great :)

Comment: Hi Dani, I made all the changes is works like a charm now :) i simply copied the column as is than ran you function and it override the text based cells, its a great solution for me im so thank full :) i have just last minor modification and i would like to add, if i want to keep your function as is with just a minor modification, auto select cells B2 to end of column instead of manually select it ? is it possible ? thx Gal

Answer (score 1):

Excel has parsed the dates according to your Windows Regional Settings short date format.  Those that it could not parse (where the month>12) it left as text.  Since there was initially a difference between the date format in the text file, and the date format in your Windows Regional settings, it is likely that many of the dates that appear as dates (or as unformatted numbers) were converted incorrectly.

You have a few options:

1. `Import` the text file using the `Get External Data` tab `From Text` option on the `Data Ribbon`.  This will open up the text import wizard and allow you to specify the date format of the data being imported.
2. Change your Windows Regional settings short date format to match that in the text file.

Those are probably the two simplest options.  The first can be automated through VBA.  The second, not so much.

Comment: Good point about the previously converted dates being wrong. In the supplied image all of the left-aligned text are in MDY and the ones that converted (right-aligned) are ambiguously DMY/MDY and have been converted wrong.

Comment: Hello Ron, I work for a very big company due to that sometimes i get information from other teams that i cannot control the quality or other reasons for inconsistency of data :) in this case the column that contains the dates came as is like that ( partially texted as in this format 3/21/16 8:54:42 PM and sometimes as a real date 07/07/2015  08:08:04 ) I have to say both cases came out of the same system which makes it odd but still yet i have to deal with it some how,  im working on automation now, that actually is already done but this little problem, I was looking for a way to use vba:)

Comment: my code is in vb so far, i managed to solve it though the excel GUI but it will required me to do this in 2 phases and im trying to avoid it

Comment: @wavestone I see you have marked a previous response as the Answer. I am glad you have a solution that works.  Just be sure that dates which could be interpreted as being either MDY or DMY (e.g. 3/8/2015 could be either 8-Mar-2015  or 3-Aug-2015) are being properly converted.

Comment: Hello Ron, yea it did land perfectly, the code was perfect i just made little modifications in sense of where to copy and what to override, thx for the tips :)